# How can I do a box for biographies?

Tags: boxes, wrapfigure, box, biography

I would like to do a box with 2 biographies. I have a code that it works but the box results small:

[image]

Like you see, the box is tight so I want to do it wider.

```
    %Formato
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}

%Simbolos y Ecuaciones
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%Biografias
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2]
{colback=#2!5!white,colframe=#2!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=#1, flushright title, width=\linewidth/2, height=10cm}

%Apariencia tabla de contenidos

\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\makeatletter
\def\tableofcontents{%
 \newpage
 \centerline{\large\scshape Tabla de Contenidos} 
 \vspace*{0.3in}
 \@mkboth{CONTENTS}{CONTENTS}
 \@starttoc{toc}
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}


%Referencias (hyperrref)
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}

%Graficos y Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%Parrafos
\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}

%Titulo
\title{Análisis de Componentes Principales}

%Informacion General
\newcommand{\theCampus}{Casa Central}
\newcommand{\theAssignment}{Probabilidad y Estadística Industrial}
\newcommand{\therevision}{BC/ML/CP/MW}

%Fecha
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}

%Cabecera y pie de página
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\pagestyle{fancy}           
\setlength{\headheight}{27pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} 

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\lhead{\includegraphics[scale=.15]{header_utfsm.png}}\cfoot{}
\cfoot{\textbf{\thepage}}
\rfoot{\therevision}
\lfoot{\theAssignment}\chead{}
\rhead{}

%--------------Portada

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{spanish}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[scale=0.38]{logo_di.png}
\vspace{-70pt}
\end{figure}
\vspace{60mm}
\begin{center}
\hrule
\vspace{2mm}
{\huge \textbf{\sc Análisis de componentes principales}}

\vspace{2mm}

{\Large \sc{Probabilidad y Estadística Industrial}}
\vspace{2mm}
\hrule
\vspace{1cm}


%Autores
\centering

{\textbf{Bárbara Cárcamo} \\
{\small Ingeniería Civil Industrial, 2016xxxxx-x, \emph{barbara.carcamo@sansano.usm.cl}}\\
\textbf{Mijail Littin} \\
{\small Ingeniería Civil Industrial, 201660007-8, \emph{mijail.littin@sansano.usm.cl }}\\
\textbf{Carlos Palma} \\
{\small Ingeniería Civil Industrial, 201660xxxx-x, \emph{carlos.palmav@sansano.usm.cl}}\\
{\textbf{Martin Weiss}\\
{\small Ingeniería Civil Industrial, 201660008-6}, \emph{martin.weiss@sansano.usm.cl}}
}

\vfill
\textsc{\monthyeardate\today}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\theCampus}
\end{center}
\clearpage
\end{titlepage}
%----------------------------------------

%Resumen Ejecutivo
\begin{abstract}
    Hola, su fortnite?
    IGUAL SI
\end{abstract}
\newpage

%Tabla de contenidos
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
%----------------------------------------

%Introducción
\section{Introducción}
Uno de los problemas centrales en el análisis de datos multivariantes es la reducción de la dimensionalidad: si es posible describir con precisión los valores de $p$ variables por un pequeño subconjunto $r<p$ de ellas, se habrá reducido la dimensión del problema a costa de una pequeña pérdida de información.

El análisis de componentes principales tiene este objetivo: dadas $n$ observaciones de $p$ variables, se analiza si es posible representar adecuadamente esta información con un número menor de variables construidas como combinaciones lineales de las originales. Por ejemplo, con variables de alta dependencia es frecuente que un pequeño número de nuevas variables (menos del 20\% de las originales) expliquen la mayor parte (más del 80\% de la variabilidad original).

La técnica de componentes principales es debida a Hotelling (1933) \cite{hotelling1933analysis}, aunque sus orígenes se encuentren en los ajustes ortogonales por mínimos cuadrados introducidos por Pearson (1901) \cite{pearson1901liii}. Su utilidad es doble:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Permite representar óptimamente observaciones de un espacio general $p-dimensional$ en un espacio de dimensión pequeña.
    \item Permite transformar las variables originales, en general correlacionadas, en nuevas variables no correlacionadas, facilitando la interpretación de los datos.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{center}

\begin{mybox}{Matemáticos relevantes}{blue}
 \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.19\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.188]{Imagenes/Harold-Hotelling.jpg}
  \end{wrapfigure}  
    \small \textbf{Harold Hotelling} (29 de septiembre de 1895 - 26 de diciembre de 1973) fue un matemático, estadístico e influyente economista. Fue profesor Asociado de Matemática en la Universidad de Stanford desde 1927 hasta 1931, miembro de la facultad de la Universidad de Columbia desde 1931 hasta 1946, y profesor de Estadística Matemática en la Universidad de Carolina del Norte en Chapel Hill desde 1946 hasta su muerte.

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.21\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.13]{Imagenes/Karl-Pearson.jpg}
  \end{wrapfigure}  
\small \textbf{Karl Pearson} (Londres 27 de marzo de 1857- Londres, 27 de abril de 1936) Científico británico. Inventor del contraste que lleva su nombre y uno de los fundadores de la Estadística en el siglo XIX. Sus trabajos sobre ajustes ortogonales precedieron el análisis de componentes principales. Fue catedrático de matemáticas y después Eugenesia en la Universidad de Londres. Fundador con Weldon, y con el apoyo económico de Galton, de la prestigiosa revista de estadística Biometrika. 
\end{mybox}
\end{center}

\newpage

%Marco teórico
\section{Marco Teórico}
\newpage

%Desarrollo de la teoría
\section{Desarrollo de la Teoría}
\newpage

%Aplicación
\section{Aplicación}
\newpage

%Conclusiones
\section{Conclusiones}
\newpage

%Bibliografía
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{bibliografia.bib}
\newpage


\end{document}

     %Simbolos y Ecuaciones
     \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

%Biografias
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2]
{colback=#2!5!white,colframe=#2!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=#1, flushright title, width=\linewidth/2, height=10cm}

%Apariencia tabla de contenidos

\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\makeatletter
\def\tableofcontents{%
 \newpage
 \centerline{\large\scshape Tabla de Contenidos} 
 \vspace*{0.3in}
 \@mkboth{CONTENTS}{CONTENTS}
 \@starttoc{toc}
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}


%Referencias (hyperrref)
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}

%Graficos y Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%Parrafos
\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}

%Titulo
\title{Análisis de Componentes Principales}

%Informacion General
\newcommand{\theCampus}{Casa Central}
\newcommand{\theAssignment}{Probabilidad y Estadística Industrial}
\newcommand{\therevision}{BC/ML/CP/MW}

%Fecha
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}

%Cabecera y pie de página
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\pagestyle{fancy}           
\setlength{\headheight}{27pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} 

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\lhead{\includegraphics[scale=.15]{header_utfsm.png}}\cfoot{}
\cfoot{\textbf{\thepage}}
\rfoot{\therevision}
\lfoot{\theAssignment}\chead{}
\rhead{}

%--------------Portada

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{spanish}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[scale=0.38]{logo_di.png}
\vspace{-70pt}
\end{figure}
\vspace{60mm}
\begin{center}
\hrule
\vspace{2mm}
{\huge \textbf{\sc Análisis de componentes principales}}

\vspace{2mm}

{\Large \sc{Probabilidad y Estadística Industrial}}
\vspace{2mm}
\hrule
\vspace{1cm}


%Autores
\centering

{\textbf{Bárbara Cárcamo} \\
{\small Ingeniería Civil Industrial, 2016xxxxx-x, \emph{barbara.carcamo@sansano.usm.cl}}\\
\textbf{Mijail Littin} \\
{\small Ingeniería Civil Industrial, 201660007-8, \emph{mijail.littin@sansano.usm.cl }}\\
\textbf{Carlos Palma} \\
{\small Ingeniería Civil Industrial, 201660xxxx-x, \emph{carlos.palmav@sansano.usm.cl}}\\
{\textbf{Martin Weiss}\\
{\small Ingeniería Civil Industrial, 201660008-6}, \emph{martin.weiss@sansano.usm.cl}}
}

\vfill
\textsc{\monthyeardate\today}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\theCampus}
\end{center}
\clearpage
\end{titlepage}
%----------------------------------------

%Resumen Ejecutivo
\begin{abstract}
    Hola, su fortnite?
    IGUAL SI
\end{abstract}
\newpage

%Tabla de contenidos
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
%----------------------------------------

%Introducción
\section{Introducción}
Uno de los problemas centrales en el análisis de datos multivariantes es la reducción de la dimensionalidad: si es posible describir con precisión los valores de $p$ variables por un pequeño subconjunto $r<p$ de ellas, se habrá reducido la dimensión del problema a costa de una pequeña pérdida de información.

El análisis de componentes principales tiene este objetivo: dadas $n$ observaciones de $p$ variables, se analiza si es posible representar adecuadamente esta información con un número menor de variables construidas como combinaciones lineales de las originales. Por ejemplo, con variables de alta dependencia es frecuente que un pequeño número de nuevas variables (menos del 20\% de las originales) expliquen la mayor parte (más del 80\% de la variabilidad original).

La técnica de componentes principales es debida a Hotelling (1933) \cite{hotelling1933analysis}, aunque sus orígenes se encuentren en los ajustes ortogonales por mínimos cuadrados introducidos por Pearson (1901) \cite{pearson1901liii}. Su utilidad es doble:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Permite representar óptimamente observaciones de un espacio general $p-dimensional$ en un espacio de dimensión pequeña.
    \item Permite transformar las variables originales, en general correlacionadas, en nuevas variables no correlacionadas, facilitando la interpretación de los datos.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{center}

\begin{mybox}{Matemáticos relevantes}{blue}
 \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.19\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.188]{Imagenes/Harold-Hotelling.jpg}
  \end{wrapfigure}  
    \small \textbf{Harold Hotelling} (29 de septiembre de 1895 - 26 de diciembre de 1973) fue un matemático, estadístico e influyente economista. Fue profesor Asociado de Matemática en la Universidad de Stanford desde 1927 hasta 1931, miembro de la facultad de la Universidad de Columbia desde 1931 hasta 1946, y profesor de Estadística Matemática en la Universidad de Carolina del Norte en Chapel Hill desde 1946 hasta su muerte.

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.21\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.13]{Imagenes/Karl-Pearson.jpg}
  \end{wrapfigure}  
\small \textbf{Karl Pearson} (Londres 27 de marzo de 1857- Londres, 27 de abril de 1936) Científico británico. Inventor del contraste que lleva su nombre y uno de los fundadores de la Estadística en el siglo XIX. Sus trabajos sobre ajustes ortogonales precedieron el análisis de componentes principales. Fue catedrático de matemáticas y después Eugenesia en la Universidad de Londres. Fundador con Weldon, y con el apoyo económico de Galton, de la prestigiosa revista de estadística Biometrika. 
\end{mybox}
\end{center}

\newpage

%Marco teórico
\section{Marco Teórico}
\newpage

%Desarrollo de la teoría
\section{Desarrollo de la Teoría}
\newpage

%Aplicación
\section{Aplicación}
\newpage

%Conclusiones
\section{Conclusiones}
\newpage

%Bibliografía
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{bibliografia.bib}
\newpage


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. If you tell us how you are doing the box, we can help you to make it wider.

Comment: If this is `tcolorbox`, you have the options `width` and `text width`.

Comment: There seem to be two documents. Also, why not post a minimal example? Yours is huge. And *never* use a `figure` environment on a title page.

Comment: Based on your use of `\newpage` and your toc-magic, you should have started with a class that suits a thesis more, one that provides chapters like you need them.

Comment: Try `width=.6\linewidth` and maybe a different height. Though i don't know why to give it a height in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much. Why can't I use a figure on title page? In this case, how can I put the university's logo on title page?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#Create_a_custom_title_for_a_report_or_book

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help. Have a nice day!